# Can you set the Natural Language of a PDF compiled with pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pdf, metadata

Can you specify the *natural language* of a PDF compiled with `pdflatex`? This [Tingtun Accessibility checker](http://checkers.eiii.eu/en/pdfcheck/) doesn't like my PDFs because this isn't set. [This page](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/PDF16) calls it the " /Lang entry in the document catalog of a PDF" and describes how to change it in Adobe Acrobat. But it would be nice to set this automatically at compile time. I would imagine that there is a setting to pass to `hyperref` to set the natural language, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Interesting link!  Thanks a lot.  I tested my actual document and it had two errors.  The natural language you mentioned and---surprise---inconsistent headers and footers.  I used KOMA-Script `scrbook` and its default headers.  I couldn't find any mistake.  Quite stunning!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following document passes the test that you linked.  It should be obvious from the example how to set the language.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Test},
  pdflang={en-US}, % PDF language identifier (RFC 3066)
}

\begin{document}

\section{foobar}

\end{document}
```

If for some reason you cannot use `hyperref`, you can also modify the PDF catalog by hand using

```
\pdfcatalog{/Lang (en-US)}
```

None of the above is sufficient if you want to generate truly accessible PDF.  All it does it shutting up this particular checker.

Comment: Outdated answer. At least the second part needs clarification since it can have adverse effects.

Comment: I suggested an edit to correct your answer. Since it got rejected I posted a new answer. After the edit it is not wrong anymore but still outdated so it does not deserve a high rank.

Answer (score 4):

The Answer of [Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10995/henri-menke) is outdated as of 2020.

There is now a more elegant way of setting the language through usage of package [`hyperxmp`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}[2020/06/15]

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\section{foobar}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `babel` you can also use

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=US]{english}
```

The advantage of the `hyperxmp` method is that it avoids a mismatch between the language in the metadata and the language used for formatting the text. Also since almost everybody uses either `babel` or `polyglossia` the code is shorter.

Do *not* use `\pdfcatalog{/Lang (en-US)}` since this method does not write XMP metadata. Some readers relying on it may not work properly. Furthermore, `\pdfcatalog` will only contain the main language whereas XMP will contain all major languages. If you do not want hyperlinks use the `NoHyper` environment.

Comment: `! Package babel Error: Unknown key for locale 'USenglish'` with TeX Live 2020.  Should I downvote now?

Comment: @HenriMenke you shouldn't downvote because this babel/Texlive issue that has nothing to do with the answer. The example works well in MikTeX and it's how it's supposed to work according to the babel documentation. Just use another language to test.

Comment: So outdated answers should be downvoted even though they were correct at the time of writing, but answers that are manifestly wrong because they produce errors deserve upvotes.  Thanks for explaining the site to me.  I'll go ahead and downvote 50% of TeX.SX now.

Comment: @HenriMenke You are welcome. SE is about answers not about egos. For TeX Live users: There is a [confirmed bug in `babel`](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/80). Use `american` instead or `polyglossia`. I am sure Javier from babel will resolve this quickly.

Comment: The issue in `babel` is resolved in 3.46. So it should work with Linux as well now.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using this as opposed to the other solution when using `hyperref` anyway?

Comment: I edited the answer in order to reply.

Comment: While this adds some metadata to the document, it does not set the Lang field in the document catalog and therefore does not satisfy the checker the question asks about.

Comment: I did not read the question as "how to satisfy the Tingtun checker" but how to set the language correctly. And the correct way of doing this is in the XMP metadata. The WCAG 2.0 standard the Tingtun checker is validating against is outdated.